# How To Random Run on line from multi lines in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

How to random run only one line from the 3 lines?

```
@echo off
xcopy /s "kk\kk-dt\eF20\kk.txt" ".\.\.\download" /Y
xcopy /s "kk\kk-dt\JUV\kk.txt" ".\.\.\download" /Y
xcopy /s "kk\kk-dt\MU\kk.txt" ".\.\.\download" /Y
pause
```

output of this code is

```
kk\kk-dt\eF20\kk.txt
1 File(s) copied
kk\kk-dt\JUV\kk.txt
1 File(s) copied
kk\kk-dt\MU\kk.txt
1 File(s) copied
```

I need only one be copied and randomly not all and overwrite ........

what i need is like some time give

```
kk\kk-dt\eF20\kk.txt
1 File(s) copied
```

or any another one of 2 others and every time bat runs gimme a random select

Comment: Hint: [Random Numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html)

Answer (score 0):

In essence you want to select randomly one of 3 or 0..2

```
@echo off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "x0=eF20"
Set "x1=JUV"
Set "x2=MU"
Set /A "y=%Random% %% 3"
echo xcopy /s "kk\kk-dt\!x%y%!\kk.txt" ".\.\.\download" /Y
pause
```

Comment: output > xcopy /s "kk\kk-dt\\kk.txt" ".\.\.\download" /Y
              Press any key to continue . . .    and didnot copy files !!

Comment: Sorry posted the wrong version with missing `/A` for the set command. Changed

Comment: thanx bro thank you so much but it worked after i removed echo before xcopy anyway thanx for your help :) good luck @lotpings